# rails console --sandbox doesn't rollback on exit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, railstutorial.org

I'm following the Ruby on Rails Tutorial, but I want to have the same environment in production as in development, that is why I setup postgres.

The thing is when I run:

```
rails console --sandbox
```

Then, I create a user and save it to the DB, I expect that on exit INSERT will be rollbacked.

But it does not. Suggestions?

Comment: What tutorial are you following? Post a link please.

Comment: There is a tag for the tutorial (railstutorial.org) http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

Comment: What version of rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue with rails 4. Take a look at this: [LINK](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9513)

Looks like there may be a fix commit at the bottom of that thread.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna ask there.